# Visual Studio Build Errors on release switch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with several projects where one of the projects houses some definitions for abstract classes. I now regularly get several build errors when i switch the release configuration from debug to release or vice versa. These errors mostly consist of errors saying that the compiler (or better to say visual studio) can't find the abstract class definitions.

This is most likely due to the fact that upon switching the release profile and performing a first build under the new configuration visual studio can't find the newly built assemblies and intellisense can't pick up on the abstract class definitions.

When i build the project two times in a row it works just as it should since visual studio is able to find the dlls that have been built before. I initially thought it was simply a problem with the build order, but apparently the build order checks out and the abstract base classes are built before the implementation classes.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you produce an [mcve]? If this is a valid VS issue, the Visual Studio dev team might be interested ...

Comment: I'm using VS 2015. I'll try to verify if the problem still exists in VS 2017 first then. If that fails to i'll look into providing a MCVE.

Comment: Did you accidentally reference the project's outputs (dll's) rather than the projects themselves?

Comment: No. Just checked and the projects are referenced, not the resulting dlls.

Comment: Check the output directories for the configurations. Are they consistent with eachother so you aren't building e.g. one projects release outputs to another's debug output dir? Easiest to put to a common directory in the root and double check to have config in the path e.g. "..\bin\AnyCPU\Release" and "..\bin\AnyCPU\Debug" for Releaseand Debug respectively in all projects.

Comment: Everything builds into its own directory in the root directory. So i have a folder in the root directory that mirrors the project setup.